# How to convert a 24 color bmp image to 16 color bmp in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

For my current task, I need to convert a 24 color bmp, to a 16 color bmp file. and Print the image in the pdf file. I tired using the PIL module,but it didn't helped me.

```
from PIL import Image

path = r'C:\Display_Icon_Testing\Captured_Images\Impl_Modulation_Screen.bmp'

im = Image.open(path)
print im
im1 = Image.open(path).convert('P')
print im1
```

please help me with this.

Comment: With '16 color bmp file', do you mean a bitmap which has only 16 colors (where each pixel is represented by a 4-bit value, which is an index into a palette), or a RGB bitmap without palette, where each pixel has 16 bits (5 bits for red, 6 bits for green, and 5 bits for blue)?  I ask this because '24 color bmp' suggests a bitmap where each pixel is represented by three bytes (for red, green and blue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will read an image in any format that PIL understands, convert it to 16 colors, and save it as a PDF file. By default, PIL uses [Floyd-Steinberg dithering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Steinberg_dithering) to improve the image quality when converting a 24 bit image to a palette-based image.

I'm using the [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/) fork of PIL, since the original PIL is no longer maintained, but this code should work properly on original PIL or Pillow.

```
from PIL import Image

iname = 'test.bmp'
oname = 'test.pdf'

img = Image.open(iname)
newimg = img.convert(mode='P', colors=16)
newimg.save(oname)
```

Comment: Thank you, very much... It really helped me...Is there any documentation, on the different modes, I wanted to know more details on it. Can you please help with this as well.. if you can...

Comment: @user2619030: Here's a list of the various PIL image [modes](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes). The simple ones should be self-explanatory, and you can learn about CMYK, HSV, YCbCr and LAB on Wikipedia. CMYK and HSV are fairly straight-forward, YCbCr and LAB are a bit more technical; LAB especially involves some advanced color space theory. If my answer has helped you, please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.